# What would change if we had room temperature superconductor now?

Tags: physics, superconductors

What would be technological impact to our every-day world, if we suddenly have room temperature super conductors ?

Specifically, what would be the major areas  of change in the immediate future (one or two years)? In other words, looking for immediate primary effects, not longer term effects such as changes in social order. Assume they would be mass producible, cheap and flexible.

Comment: I get the feeling there are so many possibilities here that it'll be hard to write and answer that is shorter than a novel.

Comment: Maglev trains would be prolific, among other things.

Comment: It really depends on the nature of the material.  Current high-temperature superconductors are more akin to brittle ceramics than flexible wires.

Comment: Are they cheap? Mass producible? Flexible?

Comment: Also, how much current can those superconductors carry? Superconductivity breaks down when the current gets too high. A room-temperature superconductor that can only carry a few milliampere per square meter would be much less useful than one that can carry a kiloampere per square micrometer.

Comment: This is a good question but at the moment it just cannot be reasonably answered in this format. You need to specify the nature of the superconductors and also focus in on where you want to know about. For example implications in transportation, computer science, etc.

Comment: @TimB There actually **is** a focus of sorts in the question. The word "suddenly" implies focus on the first wave of adaptations of the technology. That might be enough of a focus to make answer practical. It would for example exclude major infrastructure projects like maglev or electric power-grid as too time consuming. But maybe I am reading too much from a single word?

Comment: @Ville Yes,I am not taking about the long-term ones. What would be major areas that would get impacted in a near future say one or two years ? Yes they would be mass producible, cheap and flexible.