# Battling a massive army robots, how?

Tags: warfare, military-defense

In the [previous question about the great computer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73375/defeating-this-fleet), we searched for an answer to make a plan to defeat the robots in space, now, were going to look at a more "conventional" battlefield.

Note: This is the UPDATED question, change the already existing answers accordingly.

## What is the problem?

[image]

## This IS The Problem

They're just simply too many, they don't even have to think about a battle plan just go and Zerg Rush B.

## What we have to do:

- Create general battle situations, in which they are unable to use out
  their numbers.
- Find a way to bypass their air, and rocket defense, to bombard their tight formations.

**What military strategies and tactics are able to help me in this?**

## **The enemy's air defense:**

- Rockets  (against smaller rockets)
- Flak cannons (against planes and bigger rockets)
- Fake targets
- Disco smoke, can cover a 16m large circle (dissipates lasers)
- Plasma dissipating shields  (Curse you, Matthew Ward!)
- Their own planes

in an 4:4:4:4:1:4 ratio (1=10000 units of that defense type), compared to each other, because the enemy has reserves.

## My army

Is scarce, (droid army: 40000 units, **P**eacekeeping **A**utomated **F**orces: 2050 units, and while 50 of my units (The commanders) are way more powerful than jedis:

**A:** Not even they can be at multiple places.
**B:** No one can withstand a concentrated fire from the enemy.

Other PAF units are a bit better in skill than their droid army equivalents, and all of them has a droid counterpart and all droid type has a PAF counterpart.

Comment: First off, I don't understand why you are continuing to put so many distracting and off-topic pictures into your posts. You have received feedback from many people that this isn't great for question clarity. Secondly, the core question is 'idea generation,' that is, asking Worldbuilding to write a story for you. As such it is off-topic, and probably too broad and opinion based as well. I am voting to close .

Comment: @kingledion Is it ok now?

Comment: @kingledion Note, that 99% of the pictures serves as an illustration of the enemies and their abilities. (except for the patrol ships, the RAGE is strong with those)

Comment: @kingledion "off-topic" STILL!?

Comment: @kingledion I've re-edited the question to be clearer, is it ok now?

Comment: @RedactedRedacted I suggested a bigger edit. Feel free to roll back when it doesn't suit your need. That being said: I still feel like the "How to fight these squads?"-question is idea-generation. Is there a way to abstract the types of troops from the source you used? Currently this feels sort of like idea-generation for a fan-fiction.

Answer (score 1):

hacker nanites into doors and send in troops with powered armor to K.O androids without armor and mooks, then hack the signal beams so they don't know that you are stealing their battleships. Then send in plasma rifle people with powered armor troops and then destroy the octopussies by shooting under them.
After that steal the ships and get the troops on them and move away and theres victory(Of course the story would have to be more detailed but heres the idea)