# How could I scientifically explain a Vibranium-esque material?

Tags: science-based

Remember that Sci-Fi Campaign I mention in this question?: [What would the composition of an "indestructible" material be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68021/what-would-the-composition-of-an-indestructible-material-be)

Well I have more materials that need explanation (A LOT more). This next material I need an explanation for is essentially a Vibranium expy.

How could I scientifically explain the properties of Vibranium? (specifically the variant that absorbs kinetic energy to increase the strength of molecular bonds... somehow).

Comment: Do you know that gold actually gets stronger when heated... by using ultrashort laser pulses of course. It means the electrons absorb the energy but didn't have the chance to collide with other electrons(so that it can deposit excess energy), now these electrons are further from the nucleus or another word the bond just got stronger! All you have to do is substitute gold with meta-material that works with most spectrum of light, good luck.

Comment: I don't think you can do it scientifically. Techno babble and pseudo science are much more probable. Wouldn't it be enough?

Comment: Even though you specify *a* property you want to achieve, your question sounds like there are other properties you want as well. Please take some time to write down *what exactly* you want to achieve in the end (and maybe as well the *why* of this) - this will allow for much better answers as there will be less speculations.

Comment: I'd suggest that employing e.g. "indestructible" materials in stories is self-defeating.  It locks you in and prevents you from having balanced stories, as you inevitably end up with some character in an unassailable position.  It may also make progressing stories difficult.  Even Superman had Kryptonite to cope with.

Comment: No link explaining *vibranium*? Am I missing something? And *expy*? Try Googling that: *a character from one series who is unambiguously and deliberately based on a character in another, older series*. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: See [my answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68021/what-would-the-composition-of-an-indestructible-material-be/68110#68110) to this other Q.

Comment: @JDługosz I don't think it can be a duplicate when that is referenced in the OP first sentence. The OP clearly thinks a new question is being asked. I'm going with "Unclear what is being asked".

Comment: My answer on that Q is the answer here. Including how kenetic impacts just make it stronger.  So what is different here?

Answer (score 0):

"Artificially Enhanced Crystalline Structure" Changing the crystalline structure of many materials changes their attributes completely. For example, carbon, diamond, and graphene.

Using whatever technology you have in your world(i.e. nano-tech or magic) to change the shape of the crystal lattice of the base metal to give the material arbitrary attributes. As long as you keep the actual shape of the lattice unknown to the player/reader, it's theoretically possible to give vibranium-esque attributes to any number of base metals or alloys. One example of AECS in use would be transparent aluminum from Star Trek.

Comment: Can you explain that?